# Canvas javascript events on mobile

Tags: javascript, events, canvas, mobile, dom-events

I'm actually triggering all these event but none of them seems work on mobile. The canvas is actually 720x1000px and doesn't overlap all the page.

```js
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', alert);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', alert);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',   alert);
    canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", alert);
    canvas.addEventListener("touchend", alert);
    canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", alert);
    canvas.addEventListener("pointerup", alert);
    canvas.addEventListener("pointerdown", alert);
    canvas.addEventListener("pointermove", alert);
```

Is the problem caused by the events listeners or by the canvas? And how can I solve?

Answer (score 0):

> Only on mobile ?

From checking it from desktop, there is an issue that comes from the event listener, when you run it & trigger any event, it throws this error:

`TypeError: 'alert' called on an object that does not implement interface Window.`

---

The question is, what is your `alert` ?

1. If it was a custom function you defined and called `alert()`, better change the name because it already exists, it's a method of the [Window interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window).
2. If that meant to be [alert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert), then it's not a reference to a
   function, and you need to pass a **reference** to a function as a callback. If you want to call it, you need to wrap it in a function reference (an anonymous or named one) that you will pass as the callback.

---

### Different way to set the callback in the event listener

- By an anonymous function:

  ```
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(){
      alert('This is an alert');
  });
  ```

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(){
    alert('This is an alert');
});
```

```css
#canvas{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

- By a named function (with an anonymous function):

  ```
  function doAlert(msg){
      return function () {
          alert(msg);
      };
  }

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', doAlert('This is an alert'));
  ```

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

function doAlert(msg){
    return function () {
        alert(msg);
    };
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', doAlert('This is an alert'));
```

```css
#canvas{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

- By a named function (with the [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method):

  ```
  function doAlert(msg){
      return alert(msg);
  }

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', doAlert.bind(null, 'This is an alert'));
  ```

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

function doAlert(msg){
    return alert(msg);
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', doAlert.bind(null, 'This is an alert'));
```

```css
#canvas{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```